# Correlation where one of the variable is rho from a previous correlation

Tags: r, correlation

I have some data that is related to each other that looks like this.

(Using R to generate and analyze all data)

```
## Generate some data
df <- c()
Year <- c(2000:2010)
for (i in Year)
{
  n = 10; r = runif(1,0.5,1)
  x1 = rnorm(n); x2 = rnorm(n)
  y1 = scale(x2) * r  +  scale(residuals(lm(x1~x2))) * sqrt(1-r*r)
  u <- data.frame(x2=x2,y1=y1)
  u$Year <- paste0(i)
  df <- rbind(df, u)
}

> df
              x2          y1 Year
1    -0.26971369 -0.35861192 2000
2    -0.58195191 -1.16697529 2000
3     1.83715738  0.43658132 2000
4     0.70422863  0.86716364 2000
5     0.85898608  0.74443508 2000
6    -0.18313990 -2.08206890 2000
```

Now my central question how are the above variables (`x2`, `y1`) related to this data:

```
resdf <- data.frame(Year=as.character(c(2000:2010)), Response=runif(11,0,100))
```

I also have reason to believe that the correlation between `x2` and `y1` is analytically relevant. So here is where I uncertain if this is an appropriate path to take. I'll outline here with the hope that maybe I could receive some feedback that this is terrible, great or somewhere in between.

First I want to determine the correlation between `x2` and `y1` for each year. I am using the `broom` and `dplyr` packages in R to do this:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

cordf <- df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  do(tidy(cor.test(.$x2,.$y1))) %>%
  filter(p.value<0.05) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Year, estimate, p.value)
```

This generates a data frame with a correlation coefficient for each year. Now I am interested in testing how these are correlated to `resdf$Response` so I need to join those two dataframes together:

```
cordf2 <- resdf %>%
  full_join(cordf)
```

Finally I can then correlate `cordf2$Response` and `cordf2$estimate` like so:

```
cor(cordf2$Response,cordf2$estimate, use="complete.obs")
```

So my question is how appropriate is it to use the results of one correlation as the variable in another correlation? I can't think of anything mathematically wrong with this, however it does make me feel a little uneasy. Is this an appropriate approach to this problem? If not can anyone recommend a better approach to take the correlation of two variable and compare them to a subsequent variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the multiple correlation coefficient $R$ as an alternative to this approach. It provides a measure of the correlation between the best linear combination of `x2` and `y1` with your response. You can get this by fitting a linear regression `lm` object in R. The coefficients of the model may aid you in interpreting how  the relationship between `x2` and `y1` is relevant to your response. In R calling `summary` on an `lm` provides you with $R^2$. Of course you should check your relationships of interest are best described in a linear fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think you understood my question. Regression or correlation, the question is about how appropriate is it to compare the results of a regression/correlation to another variable.

Comment: Correlation is a measure of linear relation, by correlating a correlation of two variables with another variable you seem to be trying to measure how that linear joint relationship (between x2 and y1) influences the response. E.g. are you interested in questions such as when they both have high positive values (high r) does your response values around 100? The multiple correlation coefficient provides you with such information.